# Ubuntu-desktop 20.4 Nvidia drivers does not support

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, 20.04

I trying to install ubuntu on my ASUS TUF gaming lap, but its does not work. before that i use pop OS and i tying to update it for new version in that case i just lost my sound card. I really want to dual boot my lap with ubuntu OS but its not boot, i try so may times and finally I got boot it with ubuntu advance options. When i want to access my ubuntu OS i have to go with ubuntu advance options after that i try to fix Nvidia drivers but i lost ubuntu and windows in my lap. (how lucky) now i using windows but i want to ubuntu on my lap

Comment: You mention two different OSes, and I'm not sure which you're asking about.  Are you asking about Pop! OS or Ubuntu?  They are different.

Comment: sorry, I'm asking about ubuntu OS